# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:

Tags: maven

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project dashboard-backend: Compilation failure

Comment: You have a compile time error in your code.

Comment: Compiling error in your code as @tgdavies mentioned. Check that...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please provide more info or delete this post if not relevant